# HTML/Javascript Rainbow Background Code Won't Work

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I have been trying to see if it's possible to create a looping background that changes from one color to the next in a list, in the order of appearance. (The colors are: Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, and Purple.) I was hoping it would work and give a "rainbow"-type look to the page. I thought mixing HTML with JavaScript would work, but it apparently seems to show nothing but the text, and not even the first background change works.

The code is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<script>
function Red() {
bgcolor Red;
ColorOrange();
}

function Orange() {
bgcolor Orange;
ColorYellow();
}

function Yellow() {
bgcolor Yellow;
ColorGreen();
}

function Green() {
bgcolor Green;
ColorBlue();
}

function Blue() {
bgcolor Blue;
ColorPurple();
}

function Purple() {
bgcolor Purple;
ColorRed();
}



function ColorRed()
{
setTimeout("Red", 1000);
}

function ColorOrange()
{
setTimeout("Orange", 1000);
}

function ColorYellow()
{
setTimeout("Yellow", 1000);
}

function ColorGreen()
{
setTimeout("Green", 1000);
}

function ColorBlue()
{
setTimeout("Blue", 1000);
}

function ColorPurple()
{
setTimeout("Purple", 1000);
}
</script>

There is text here, but it's sorta not related to this so I replaced it with this!
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You declare a lot of methods, but you don't call any of them. Also, I don't think that `bgcolor Blue` is valid JavaScript.

Comment: By 'rainbow', I think of multiple colors at once, but your code and your explanation suggest you want to change the complete background to one color change that color every second. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was trying to implement the HTML code for changing the background color, bgcolor, into my JavaScript. Is there a way to put HTML into my JavaScript?

Comment: bgcolor is an old attribute and is not even supported in HTML5. You should use css/styles for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to put the colors in an array. You can simply loop through the array and use the setInterval function to change the color each second.

```js
(function() { // Wrap in a function to not pollute the global scope

  // Colors. These are the color names you can use in CSS. You could use color codes
  // like #rrggbb as well.
  var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple'];

  var colorIndex = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
    // Set the color and increment the index.
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex++];

    // Wrap the index if it goes past the length of the array. % is modulo.
    colorIndex %= colors.length;
    }, 1000);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use Java.

Add this to any tag:

```
style="linear-gradient(red,orange,yellow,green,cyan,blue,magenta)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this cool code to do it.
And also [on github](https://github.com/gn-venpy/rainbow-html-background/blob/main/index.html).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Rainbow Background</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let r = 255
        let g = 0
        let b = 0
        
        function rgb(r, g, b){
            return "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"
        }
        
        function myTimer () {
            if (r < 255 && g == 0 && b == 0) {
                r++
            } else if (r == 255 && g < 255 && b == 0) {
                g++
            } else if (r > 0 && g == 255 && b == 0) {
                r--
            } else if (r == 0 && g == 255 && b < 255) {
                b++
            } else if (r == 0 && g > 0 && b == 255) {
                g--
            } else if (r < 255 && g == 0 && b == 255) {
                r++
            } else if (r == 255 && g== 0 && b > 0) {
                b--
            }
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb(r, g, b)
        }
        
        setInterval(myTimer, 10)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html,body{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            display: grid;
            grid-auto-flow: column;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let CI=0;
        let PI=2;
        const saturation = 0;// max 255
        const value = 255;// max 255
        let CC=[saturation,saturation,value];
        for(i=1;i=1;){
            if(CC[CI]<value){
                CC[CI]++;
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = `${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]}`;div.className = "part";
                document.querySelector("body").appendChild(div);
                document.getElementById(`${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]}`).setAttribute("style",`background-color:rgb(${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]});`);
                document.body.setAttribute("style",`background-color:rgb(${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]});`);
            } else if(CC[PI]>saturation){
                CC[PI]--;
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id = `${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]}`;div.className = "part";
                document.querySelector("body").appendChild(div);
                document.getElementById(`${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]}`).setAttribute("style",`background-color:rgb(${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]});`);
                document.body.setAttribute("style",`background-color:rgb(${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]});`);
            } else {
                PI=CI;
                if(CI<2){
                    CI++;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let CI=0;
        let PI=2;
        const saturation = 0;
        const value = 255;
        let CC=[saturation,saturation,value];
        count=0;
        let loop = setInterval(function(){
            if(CC[CI]<value){
                CC[CI]++;
            } else if(CC[PI]>saturation){
                CC[PI]--;
            } else {
                PI=CI;
                if(CI<2){
                    CI++;
                }else{
                    CI=0;
                }
            }
            document.body.setAttribute("style",`background-color:rgb(${CC[0]},${CC[1]},${CC[2]});`);
        },1);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).