# Changing Background Color according to time

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, background-color

I'm coding a site with my friend, we are very new to coding. We would like our site to change color gradually every second according to the time of day. We have no clue where to even start, other than using a javascript function. Please help!!!! We have coded a clock into our site

```
function time(){
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours()
if (h>12) {h= h- "12"} ;
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('clocky').innerHTML =
h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

var t = setTimeout(time, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
return i;
}
```

This is as far as we have gotten other than general html for the clock and css. How would you code the changing background according to time?

Comment: well, you could start with `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"`...

Comment: do you want a random color each second or some sort of rainbow transition???

Comment: Sort of a rainbow transition, but with different shades of each color so they last a decent amount of time. The goal is to not repeat a color.

Comment: btw about the rainbow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847222/html-javascript-rainbow-background-code-wont-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/f9b9sbr4/1/

```
function time(){
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours()
  if (h>12) {h= h- "12"} ;
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('clocky').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var r = parseInt(s) * 1;
  var g = parseInt(s) * 3;
  var b = parseInt(s) * 5;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  var t = setTimeout(time, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
    return i;
}

time();
```

Comment: it depends on the seconds, and as Daniel has mentioned, you can relate on any of params from both sides: Red, Green, Blue and Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a simple mistake. It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: So, this works. It only goes through shades of blue. How do we get it to go through more colors?

Answer (score 1):

Well, now you'll need to make some decisions.

CSS lets you specify colors in the RGB format using numeric values from 0-255 (e.g. `background-color: rgb(0,0,0)` for a black background, and `background-color: rgb(255,255,255)` for a white background.

Assuming you want to use that method for specifying the color, you'll need to decide how you want the current time to map to those values. Once you have that figured out, all you'll need to do is set the background color style on the `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question asks for a javscript solution, but the animation you are seeking is possible with a css-only solution and should be more performant.

I've written a more complete solution using a tiny bit of php to fetch daylight information for given lat/long coordinates and change the color of the page in real-time according to the time of day.

**for a demo see here:**
http://shawnfromportland.com/circadianCssWithPhp/

**for the source check it out here:**
https://github.com/shawnfromportland/circadianCssWithPhp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That goes for all your recent answers which are essentially the same.